# Composer works as root but not as a common user, why?

Tags: centos, php, environment-variables, command-line-interface

I have installed Composer Globally as [this](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally) docs shows and it works for `root` user on my server CentOS 6.6 but as a normal user lets said `webvm` user it doesn't saying that composer is not found (see below):

```
[webvm@webvm ~]$ sudo composer
[sudo] password for webvm:
sudo: composer: command not found
```

Do I need to setup something else in order to get composer working from a non root user? `webvm` is in sudoers file so I not know what I'm missing here, any advice?

Comment: I'd like to point out that composer should **NOT** be run as root, and `sudo composer` should not be run in the normal course of development or deployment. The unprivileged application/webserver user should be using composer **WITHOUT** sudo. The only time I'd even consider `sudo composer` would be with the `self-update` command, never `install` or `update`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of two issues are likely reasons:

- Either it's not in `webvm`s `$PATH`
- It's only executable for root. Check the permissions

Comment: This are the permissions for the file `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1029339 Dec  1 20:01 /usr/local/bin/composer` how I can fix the issue? What I should do on my server in order to get composer working out of root user?

Comment: See if `sudo /usr/local/bin/composer` works. If it does, you have to add `/usr/local/bin` to your `$PATH`.

Comment: That works, where I should add this to the `$PATH`? In `home/webvm/.bashrc` file? What line I should add?

Comment: @ReynierPM: [SF] is a site for pro admins. You are expected to know such fundamentals or be able to learn them yourself. Google exists. And yes, `~/.bashrc` might be an option if you use `bash`.

Comment: I have run the command `echo "$PATH"` and I able to see the route where composer file is: `/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/webvm/bin` then why isn't executed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257616/sudo-changes-path-why